# Когда использовать cookie, а когда localstorage?

Tags: javascript, cookie, localstorage

Cookie и localstorage - второе полностью заменяет первое, или все зависит от ситуации? Если зависит от ситуации, то как понять, когда использовать одно, а когда другое?

Коллеги, спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Cookie передаются на сервер при каждом запросе — вот и имеет смысл использовать их для чего-то, что нужно на сервере. Скажем, авторизация, или, например, параметры вида, нужные при сборке страницы на сервере, такие как язык.

Всё остальное, нужное лишь на уровне фронтенда, как я понимаю, лучше держать в Local Storage. Туда и влезет больше, и проблем с переполнением не будет (если куков слишком много, некоторые сервера могут перестать выдавать какой-бы то ни было ответ вообще).

Если же нужна поддержка абсолютно всех браузеров вроде IE7, я бы советовал воспользоваться полифиллом, чтобы и в таком случае куки использовались лишь как последнее средство.

Answer (score 3):

Cookie очень ограничены. В одной cookie может быть всего 4096 символов, а их количество на один домен примерно 30-50 в зависимости от браузера. В локальном хранилище мы можем хранить 5-10мб или даже больше на длительное время.

Самое большое отличие cookie от localStorage - это то, что первый работает с сервером, а второй нет.

Источник: https://myrusakov.ru/html5-local-storage.html

Answer (score -1):

Через Cookie сработает CSRF-attack, а через local/session storage нет, так как они не передаются автоматически с запросом и доступны только на установленном домене.